# Refactor all Vue component imports to append .vue extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, refactoring, es6-modules

The Vue CLI is dropping support for extensionless imports, and various features supported by VS Code extensions like Vetur don't work with extensionless imports.

I have a need to modify every default component import from a `.vue` file to append the extension across the entire codebase. Due to the number of files this is infeasible to do by hand, and some automated method is necessary.

Examples:

Turn:

```js
import Baz from '@/components/Baz'
import Thing from './LocalThing'
import OtherThing from '../../OtherThing'
```

into:

```js
import Baz from '@/components/Baz.vue'
import Thing from './LocalThing.vue'
import OtherThing from '../../OtherThing.vue'
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex Find Replace with

**Find**:

```
^import (.*?)(?<!\.vue)'$
```

**Replace**

```
import $1.vue'
```

Don't replace the once already done.

It should work in Find/Replace in Files.

**Edit**

Then you have to construct a regex based on the filenames that end in `.vue`

```
find . -name "*.vue"
```

Then construct a regex with the file basenames:

```
^import (.*?(?:Baz|LocalThing|OtherThing))(?<!\.vue)'$
```

Comment: Not every import in a project imports from `vue` component files... which is why this is tricky. There are plenty of import from packages and other js & ts files that will always be there.

I need to make this change ONLY for imports from files that end in `.vue`, which means a regex global search won't work unless it can perform module resolution and read the imported file names/locations?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell see the edit, you have to incorporate the filenames

Comment: Wow you are a godsend. You deserve way more than a simple upvote. I am using import aliases, so modifying it to capture my folder structure was very simple, even with me being terrified of regex.

Comment: @Grant You can give this question a bounty ;-)

Comment: Coming your way in 23 hours.

Comment: if you need to examine lines that end with `;`, use `^import (.*?)(?<!\.vue)';$`

Answer (score 1):

When I was migrating a project from Vue CLI to Vite I had the same exact problem. I managed to solve it using a dirty Node.js script where you can replace some configs:

```
const path = require('path')
const replace = require('replace-in-file')
const fs = require('fs')

const FILES_TO_REPLACE_GLOB = 'src/**/*.*'
const ALIAS_PATH = '@/'
const ALIAS_DESTINATION = 'src/'

const exportDefaultWithoutVueExtension = /^import \w+( as \w+)? from '(.*?)(?<!\.vue)'$/gm
let replacements = 0

console.log('\nReplacing imports...\n')

replace.sync({
  //dry: true,
  encoding: 'utf8',
  files: FILES_TO_REPLACE_GLOB,
  from: exportDefaultWithoutVueExtension,
  to: (match, g1, importPath, offset, string, file) => {
    const isNodeModuleImport = /^\w/.test(importPath)
    if (isNodeModuleImport) return match

    const currentFolder = path.dirname(file)
    const isAliasPath = new RegExp('^' + ALIAS_PATH).test(importPath)
    let importFilePath = isAliasPath
      ? importPath.replace(ALIAS_PATH, ALIAS_DESTINATION)
      : path.resolve(currentFolder, importPath)

    const importIsVueFile = fs.existsSync(importFilePath + '.vue')
    if (!importIsVueFile) return match

    const newPath = importPath + '.vue'
    replacements++
    console.log(`${file} import changed to ${newPath}`)
    return match.replace(importPath, newPath)
  }
})

console.log('\n' + replacements + ' replacements were done.')
```

You will need to first install [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) provisionally in your project as it's a dependency:

```
npm i replace-in-file
```

Then you can simply run it with:

```
node <scriptName>.js
```

I hope this helps others with the same problem in the future.